# How can I resolve leaking memory in the cypress?

Tags: cypress

There is React Application (ant).
Cypress 10.3.1.

testList.cy.js:

```
import './1_test.cy';
...
import './30_test.cy';
```

test.cy.js:

```
describe('test' , () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.intercept('/login').as('makeLogin')
    cy.makeLogin();
    cy.wait('@makeLogin')
    cy.wait(0)
  });

  it('TEST' , () => {

    cy.visit('https://localhost:3000/home')
    cy.wait(0)

    cy.get('.element')
      .should('be.visible')
      .click({ force:true }); // This string doesn't operate as expected

  })
})
```

config.cy.js:

```
  numTestsKeptInMemory: 1,
  pageLoadTimeout: 60000,
  defaultTimeout: 30000,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 40000,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  responseTimeout: 60000,
  timeout: 60000
```

Command.js :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('makeLogin', () => {
  ... command description ...
  });
});
```

I execute each test (from 1 to 30). Tests operate as expected.
But if I execute testList.cy.js I had problem:

1. I launch cypress open and execute testList.cy.js.
   Actual result: Cypress application falled
2. I use cypress run --spec 'cypress/e2e/testList.cy.js' --browser chrome .
   Actual Result: The testList.cy.js faulted. Few tests '№_test.cy.js' fall on the string (I marked this string in the test.cy.js)

I guess that it is leaking memory, maybe. Maybe, can I clear cypress cash before each №_test.cy.js in the testList.cy.js file? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the task manager? Any information whatsoever on memory consumption? What is the click handler doing? Why do you need to force-click it? The large timeouts indicate something badly wrong with the app.